# How define pull request destination Git branch? For Stash

Tags: git, branch, fetch, pull-request, bitbucket-server

Fetch:

```
git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@gitscm.company.com/project/repository.git +refs/pull-requests/*:refs/remotes/origin/pull-request/*
```

Result:

```
 + 6f39c4e...b2fd4cd refs/pull-requests/1139/merge -> origin/pull-request/1139/merge  (forced update)
 + b4f274b...dd71491 refs/pull-requests/1499/merge -> origin/pull-request/1499/merge  (forced update)
```

But there are no information about destination branch.
How define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [REST API](https://gitscm.company.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT/repos), I think it should help you.